# Can't to log in postgres account by pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql

Before I changed my forgotten postgres pass using 'su - root' in command line.
Then I try to connect server using pgAdmin and I get error:

```
Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

But in command line I successfully log in postgres account:

```
su - postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a `postgres` unix user account password, which you can change using `passwd` as `root`.

There is also a *totally unrelated* `postgres` role in the database, which might have a password of its own. This is totally unaffected by the `passwd` command. If you have forgotten this password, you have to reset it within PostgreSQL. See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/10845998/398670
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/19643/7788

etc.

The reason it works from `psql` but not PgAdmin is probably that you'll be using a unix socket with `psql`, using `peer` authentication to bypass password auth completely. If you've got `localhost` in your connection setup for PgAdmin it'll use TCP/IP instead, which is probably set to require `md5` password authentication. Check your `pg_hba.conf` to confirm.

Comment: I've changed pg_hba.conf.  I put 'trust' in place of 'peer'/'md5' of localhost.

Comment: @Alex If you did so for both `host` and `local` lines, and reloaded/restarted PostgreSQL, you should be able to log in fine. Though of course so can anyone else with access to your machine.

Comment: Yes, I restarted Postgres Server. It's a part of pg_hba.conf      Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                trust
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 trust

Comment: Ouch. I did it :) It seems I didn't close pg_hba.conf and tried to connect server)